# Molecular Docking using Quantum Computing

Tags: superconducting-quantum-computing, chemistry, openfermion

I would like to ask if somebody could **suggest me a pair of ligand-Protein** which had been validated and the corresponding resulting drug is already being used commercially.

I am interested in experimenting with this ligand-Protein pair, to reverse engineer the molecular docking procedure using Quantum Computing.

Comment: How are you planning to use current quantum computer for such task? What algorithms are you planning to use to reverse engineer the molecular docking procedure?

Comment: Based on some papers which advocates about using Gaussian Boson Sampling and then QAOA as an algorithm by converting the physical fitment of ligand-Protein to a max-cliq problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @KAJ226

Comment: See this answer: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/423/5